# Common Control for all pages

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, user-controls

I wanted to make **Header User Control** that should be available on the top of all the pages in windows phone 8 app.I don't want to declare this control on all the pages and also its functionality will going to be same on different pages.
It would be like **Application bar**. So, where should i have to declare or define this control such that above mentioned goals can be fulfilled ?

Comment: It is nice to tell us what you intend to do. Please ask a question. [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great. In this case you can create a custom user control. Create your bar with all necessary things (buttons, images etc).
Add all handlers in this user control itself. Now that you have this control ready. You can just add this control like any other control onto a xaml page where you wish to have it. It will just require your namespace to be present in the xaml.

eg:

```
    xmlns:animateMenu="clr-namespace:AppNameSpace.Presentation"
```

This namespace once added will let you access your user control everywhere.
using it this way:

```
    <animateMenu:Menu  x:Name="MyMenu"/>
```

**EDIT**
Code to place in app.xaml

```
<shell:ApplicationBar x:Key="CommonAppBar" IsVisible="True">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Resources/Images/Appbar.btn1.png" Text="home" x:Name="abibtnHome" Click="ApplicationBarIconButton_Click"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Resources/Images/Appbar.btn2.png" Text="search" x:Name="abibtnSearch" Click="ApplicationBarIconButton_Click"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Resources/Images/Appbar.btn3.png" Text="call" x:Name="abibtnCall" Click="ApplicationBarIconButton_Click"/>


            <!-- added for menus in the app bar-->
            <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>                    
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem x:Name="menuitemSettings"  Text="menu1" Click="menu1_Click"/>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem x:Name="menuitemAbout" Text="menu2"    Click="menu2_Click"/>
           </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
 </shell:ApplicationBar>
```

Hope this helps.
Thanks and Cheers.

Comment: Just make sure you do not want any page specific functionality to happen over this app bar kind of menu. i.e. Be sure that on all pages he app bar will behave the same way irrespective of what page you are on,currently. Else you will need to handle and manage some code in your xaml page as well.

Comment: I don't want to make these instances on each and every page.It would be like i declare this somewhere and it will propegate to all the pages all by its own

Comment: Even for the default app bar, It needs to be placed separately on every page. I can suggest you another piece of code. You can have this code piece in you app.xaml and have your handlers in app.xaml.cs.
However you will need to add it separately in all your xamls. I don't see any direct way you can have just a single of that bar working for all pages.